# Laravel sign in form does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm learning Laravel 5.3 and I have made a simple login form which goes like this and is saved in the file `login.blade.php` under the `auth` directory in `resources/views`:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="login">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" size="40"><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" size="40"><br>
            <input hidden name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in `web.php` I have added this:

```
    Route::post('/login','Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout','Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

So it is very simple and clear ,however whenever I try to login with my correct credentials it won't work and stays in the login page.

Here is the print screen of my `users` table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMJ80.png)

Note that db is already connected and there's no need to mention that..

Comment: Lets have a look at `LoginController@login`.

Comment: How did you create the password for this? If you registered using laravel register page this password should be hashed. Laravel native login controller will be expecting a hashed value.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I'll try it

Comment: I generated a hash and replaced it with the 123 pass but it still does not log me in !!!

Answer (score 0):

did you hashed the password with `bcrypt` command?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to hash your password by using `bcrypt()` function when using laravel out of the box Authentication and when using Auth: `Auth::attempt()`.